# Ranking 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, ranking

i have 3 tables and I’m trying to rank 2 different date columns from 2 different tables

t1:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| SSS | 121 |

t2:

| Name | ID | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SSS | 121 | 02/02/20021 |
| SSS | 121 | 02/28/20021 |

t3:

| Name | ID | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SSS | 121 | 03/03/20021 |
| SSS | 121 | 03/01/20021 |

using below query:

```
    With main_code as
 (  Select
         t1.name
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.Id ,t2.start_date ORDER BY t2.I’d DESC) AS rnk1
        ,t2.start_date
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t3.Id ,t3.end_date ORDER BY t3.I’d DESC) AS rnk2 
        ,t3.end_date

From t1 
Left outer join t2 On t1.Id = t2.Id 
Left outer join t3 on t1.Id = t3.Id  )

Select * from Main_code 
Where rnk1=1 and rnk2=1
```

when i use this i do not get anything:

| Name | rnk1 | start_date | rnk2 | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blank | blank | blank | blank | blank |

but when i use OR i get:

| Name | rnk1 | start_date | rnk2 | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SSS | 1 | 02/28/20021 | 2 | 03/01/20021 |
| SSS | 2 | 02/02/20021 | 1 | 03/03/20021 |

While i should get :

| Name | rnk1 | start_date | rnk2 | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SSS | 1 | 02/28/20021 | 1 | 03/03/20021 |

How can i fix this code?

Comment: your sample data are totally not valid. `02/31/20021` . Maybe in the year `20021` there will be `31` days in the month of `Feb`

Comment: I think your sample data tables are incorrect - t3 does not have a column named "end_date"

Comment: It’s a typo,, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've:

- joined the two tables together
- then added rank columns
- the looked for a row where they both have rank = 1.

What you need to do is:

- Add a rank column to each table
- look for the rows where ranks match
- join the results.

Something like:

```
With main_code as
 (  
 Select
    t1.name
    ,t2_1.rnk1
    ,t2_1.start_date
    ,t3_1.rnk2 
    ,t3_1.start_date as end_date 

From t1 
Left outer join
(Select start_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, start_date ORDER BY id DESC) AS rnk1 from t2) as t2_1
On t1.Id = t2_1.Id 

Left outer join 
(Select start_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, start_date ORDER BY id DESC) AS rnk2 from t3) as t3_1
on t1.Id = t3_1.Id 

Where t2_1.rnk1 = r3_1.rnk2
)

Select * from Main_code 
Where rnk1=1
```

Comment: could you post your sample output?

Comment: Sorry doing it blind - don't have anywhere to run it this moment.

Comment: As noted above, the start_date / end_date naming is a bit off.  This deals with the jist of the problem, the small print will need sorting out.

Comment: Updated - matches example structure now.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the last dates from `t2` and `t3` for each `id` of `t1`, use `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name, 
       MAX(t2.start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id) start_date, 
       MAX(t3.end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Id) end_date 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.Id = t3.Id;
```

Or better with 2 correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.name,
       (SELECT MAX(t2.start_date) FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id) start_date, 
       (SELECT MAX(t3.start_date) FROM t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.id) end_date 
FROM t1;
```